# Videojs sometimes does not occur and gives an error In my Reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

In the ReactJs code below, videojs sometimes doesn't occur and gives an error. Sometimes when I open the 5th video, sometimes when I open the 30th video. So it's not clear when he made a mistake.
If I enclose the try catch block, I get through the error, but when I try to open a new video, videojs does not occur for approximately 2-3 minutes. As if it is still repairing or reinstalling videojs.

```
const Player = ({ onPlayerInit }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
  
    if (!videoRef || !onPlayerInit) return;
  // try {
    const initPlayer = videojs(videoRef.current, {}, function () {

      //videojs(videoRef.current erorr!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

      console.log("player ready");
    });
   
    initPlayer && onPlayerInit(initPlayer);

    initPlayer &&
      initPlayer.getChild("controlBar").addChild("vjsEpisodeList", {});

    // } catch (error) {
   
    //   dispatch(setVodError(true));
  
    // }

    return () => {
      initPlayer && initPlayer.dispose();
    };
  }, [onPlayerInit]);

  return (
    <div className="inner-container" data-vjs-player tabIndex="-1">
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        controls
        data-setup="{}"
        className="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

Comment: Can you provide error message please?

Comment: Sorry, you're right .. Error message: "Invalid target; must be a DOM node or evented object" but I get this error in another related event. Because videojs does not occur.

Comment: I have the same issue and it makes no sense, 
It functions correct after first load but fails when I have disposed the player and reinitialized it on a new route/dependency.

When I do ```player.playlist.currentItem(0);``` no error, 
and the next line it throws me the error on: ```player.one('playlistitem', () =>...```.
I "solved" it by putting ```player = document.querySelector('.video-js').player;``` before it.